# Backup automático com MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

É possível realizar backup automático no mysql?
Exemplo: Direciono uma pasta a qual o Mysql irá gerar todos os dias as 18:00 o backup do banco de dados.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Eu fiz uma automação dessa criando um arquivo .bat com os comandos e configurando a execução no Agendador de Tarefas do Windows, segue abaixo o meu arquivo bat:

```
@echo off
cls

REM Define o usuário e senha do banco de dados
set dbUser=xxx
set dbPassword=xxx

REM Define a pasta que será feito o backup no padrão ...\<dia do mês>\<hora atual>
set backupDir=C:\Backup\MySQL\%date:~0,2%\%time:~0,2%\

REM Nome do arquivo que será gerado
set file=xxx.sql

REM Caminho dos executáveis do mysqldump.exe, para executar o dump, e do 7z.exe, para compactar o arquivo
set mysqldump="C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin\mysqldump.exe"
set zip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

REM Cria a pasta de backup caso não exista
if not exist "%backupDir%" (
    mkdir "%backupDir%"
)

REM Executa o dump, aqui precisa configurar o host e o nome do banco de dados (locais com xxx)
%mysqldump% --host="xxx" --user=%dbUser% --password=%dbPassword% xxx > "%backupDir%\%file%"

REM Compacta o arquivo com o dump
%zip% a -tgzip "%backupDir%\%file%.gz" "%backupDir%\%file%"

REM Exclui o arquivo .sql original
del "%backupDir%\%file%"
```

No caso, ele cria uma pasta para o dia do mês, faz o dump e compacta o arquivo.

Comment: Bacana, antes de testar, poderia detalhar a funcionalidade das linhas:
set backupDir=C:\Backup\MySQL\%date:~0,2%\%time:~0,2%\
set mysqldump="C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin\mysqldump.exe"
set zip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

Comment: Comentei o código :)